# Repeater inside repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, datasource

I've one repeater (REPEATER SON) inside another repeater (REPEATER FATHER)...

In codeside I set the `repeaterSON` datasource with a list SON1, and the `repeaterFATHER` with list FATHER1.

In clientside (ASPX), in repeaterSON i get some label texts with `<%#Eval("propObjrepeaterSON)"%>...` and in repeaterFATHER some label texts with `<%#Eval("propObjFATHER1")%>`.

In clientside, how do I get the value of SON1 list in repeater B ?

Comment: Use appropriate naming/id/css class conventions and use jQuery to select them.

Comment: I advice you use Firebug in FireFox, Webmaster tools in Explorer or Webmaster tools in Chrome (F12) and find the object you want to know his name. Then, use JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Give each repeaterSON a unique id, e.g. `repeaterSON_<%#Eval("sonID")#>`. Then you can get the specific repeaterSON using jQuery.